# CodeIgniter login and session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I am currently building a web for **student registration** and I am using CodeIgniter. I already managed to insert the form to my database and I am using email and password from the submitted form to login. I got a problem in my login page,somehow it cant check either the email or password exists on the database or not and it cant redirect to my desired page either.

This is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data = '';
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','md5|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {    
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

            $this->load->model('testmodel','user');

            $member = $this->user->selectUser("WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");

            if($member->has_rows())
            {
                $user_data = array(
                                'name'  => $member->row('name'),
                                'nisn'  => $member->row('nisn'),
                                'email'     => $member->row('email'),
                                'logged_in_admin' => TRUE
                           );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data); redirect('pages/userpage/userpage');
            }else 
            {
                $data['message'] = '<div class = "error">Username and password wrong!</div>';
            }
        }else 
        {
            $data['message'] = '<div class = "error">' . validation_errors() .  '</div>';
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('pages/userlogin/userlogin',$data);
}
```

This is the selectuser function in testmodel

```
public function selectUser($where = '', $sort = 'DESC', $limit = '')
{
    $query = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM student_table
            $where
        ORDER BY ticketnumber $sort
            $limit
    ";
    return $this->db->query($query);
}'
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Do you have a working database connection independently tested from your code?

Comment: theres no error,its just cant redirect to my desired page and yes its is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to login with the use of session.

```
public function index()
{
  //get the posted values
  $email= $this->input->post("email");
  $password = $this->input->post("password");

  //set validations
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email", "trim|required");
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
       //validation fails
       $this->load->view('Your_Login_View');
  }
  else
  {
       //validation succeeds
       if ($this->input->post('btn_login') == "Login")
       {
            //check if Email and password is correct
            $usr_result = $this->testmodel->selectUser($email, $password);
            if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
            {
                 //set the session variables
                 $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                 $_SESSION['loginuser'] = true;

                redirect("Your_Desired_page");
            }
            else
            {
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid email and password!</div>');
                 redirect('admin');
            }
       }
       else
       {
            redirect('admin');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this Your Controller:

```
public function index()
 {
      //get the posted values
      $email= $this->input->post("email");
      $password = $this->input->post("password");


      //set validations
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email", "trim|required");
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
           //validation fails
           $this->load->view('Your_Login_View');
      }
      else
      {
           //validation succeeds
           if ($this->input->post('btn_login') == "Login")
           {
                //check if Email and password is correct
                $usr_result = $this->testmodel->selectUser($email, $password);
                if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                {
                     //set the session variables
                     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                     $_SESSION['loginuser'] = true;

                    redirect("Your_Desired_page");
                }
                else
                {
                     $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid email and password!</div>');
                     redirect('admin');
                }
           }
           else
           {
                redirect('admin');
           }
      }
 }
```

Your Model:

```
function selectUser($email, $password)
 {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('student_table');
      $this->db->where('email',$email);
      $this->db->where('password',$password);
      $query = $this->db->get();

      return $query->num_rows();


 }
```

Comment: i got another problem, whenever i submitted it only redirect me to the admin page not my desired page although i've insert the correct email and password..any clue ?

Comment: it means that your code jumps in else part every time make sure that your submit button has name="btn_login" and value="Login