# Cant login with email and username that is on database (Codeigniter php)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

i already have database with table of username, email (primary key), and password and have already filled them. but when i try to put those emails and password on my web page, it is read as wrong.

Here is my login controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //load the required libraries and helpers for login
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library(['form_validation','session']);
        $this->load->database();

        //load the Login Model
        $this->load->model('LoginModel', 'Login_controller');
    }
    public function index() {
        //check if the user is already logged in 
        $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if($logged_in){
            //if yes redirect to welcome page
            redirect(base_url().'HomeLoggedIn_controller/index/');
        }
        //if not load the login page
        $this->load->view('login/v_login');
    }
    public function doLogin() {
        //get the input fields from login form
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

        //send the email pass to query if the user is present or not
        $check_login = $this->Login_controller->checkLogin($email, $password);
        //if the result is query result is 1 then valid user
        if ($check_login) {
            //if yes then set the session 'loggin_in' as true
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
            redirect(base_url().'HomeLoggedIn_controller/index/');
        } else {
            //if no then set the session 'logged_in' as false
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', false);

            //and redirect to login page with flashdata invalid msg
            //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username / Password Invalid');
            redirect(base_url().'Login_controller/index/');            
        }
    }
    public function logout() {
        //unset the logged_in session and redirect to login page
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        redirect(base_url().'Login_controller/index/');
    }
}
```

login model:

```
<?php
class LoginModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function checkLogin($email, $password) {
        //query the table 'users' and get the result count
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('tb_user');
        return $query->num_rows();

    }
}
```

i try the controller and model from a website and i've already change certain things on my view page to sync it with the controller.

Comment: is the password stored as sha1 hash ?

Comment: $check_login = $this->Login_controller->checkLogin($email, $password); this is wrong change it to model name.

Answer (score 1):

Hello if I may get you right you want to verify the login detail from your model. Please use this in your controller. I hope this will help you solve you issue.

```php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //load the required libraries and helpers for login
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library(['form_validation','session']);
        $this->load->database();

        //load the Login Model
        $this->load->model('LoginModel', 'Login_controller');
    }
    public function index() {
        //check if the user is already logged in 
        $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if($logged_in){
            //if yes redirect to welcome page
            redirect(base_url().'HomeLoggedIn_controller/index/');
        }
        //if not load the login page
        $this->load->view('login/v_login');
    }
    public function doLogin() {
        //get the input fields from login form
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

        //send the email pass to query if the user is present or not
        $check_login = $this->LoginModel->checkLogin($email, $password);
        //if the result is query result is 1 then valid user
        if ($check_login) {
            //if yes then set the session 'loggin_in' as true
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
            redirect(base_url().'HomeLoggedIn_controller/index/');
        } else {
            //if no then set the session 'logged_in' as false
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', false);

            //and redirect to login page with flashdata invalid msg
            //$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username / Password Invalid');
            redirect(base_url().'Login_controller/index/');            
        }
    }
    public function logout() {
        //unset the logged_in session and redirect to login page
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        redirect(base_url().'Login_controller/index/');
    }
}
```

**Error discovered! you did not load the model method checklogin well**


You used `$this->Login_controller->checkLogin($email, $password);` instead of `$this->LoginModel->checkLogin($email, $password);`. Which result to your error. Please replace your code with mine.
I hope this helped you if not call my attention, okay

Comment: i got an error on line 
`$check_login = $this->LoginModel->checkLogin($email, $password);`

then i changed the
`$this->load->model('LoginModel', 'Login_controller');`
into:
`$this->load->model('LoginModel');`

and then theres no more error but my email and password still considered wrong even though it is the exact same then the one on my database

Comment: @ajubo explain to me what is your new error clearly. is it that you can not fetch the user data. if yes session the user id or anything that will help identify the user data from the database. If this is not what you are looking for then clear my confusion or try this [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45476313/11716584). I hope this will help you more and let me know if it does

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$check_login = $this->Login_controller->checkLogin($email, $password);
```

To:

```
$check_login = $this->checkLogin($email, $password);
```